# Oil change VOLVO S60 D4

Tags: oil-change, service

I have an S60 volvo D4. The local service performs a general service every 20K and a small service only for oil change in the middle of that period, that is in 10K.

Does the only for oil service really needed ? If I skip that intermid oil change, will I harm my machine ?

Note that I make a lot of highway kilometers. 70% of my mileage are on highway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manufacturer designs a service schedule to keep the vehicle in good condition.

If you ignore service schedules then that will affect the service life of the engine, and missed items in the service schedule may possibly affect the resale value in the future.

I would respect the oil change intervals for your car.

I did double the oil change intervals on a car I had - I was using Mobil 1 5W-50 at the time BUT I did change the oil filter at the normal interval, worked for me (but I had changed the engine and done the conversion myself).